# Add "Show Desktop" shortcut to plank

Tags: plank

I am using Plank on Ubuntu 14.04, I want to add "show desktop" shortcut to plank so that whenever I click it I get to see the desktop directly instead of minimizing all the windows. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all install the **xdotool**:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
2. **Create a Desktop Shortcut** for the 'Show Desktop' for simulate the press key <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> using xdotool:

   ```
   sudo nano /usr/share/applications/show-desktop.desktop
   ```

   Add below contents:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]  
   Type=Application  
   Exec=xdotool key --delay 100 super+d  
   Name=Show Desktop  
   Icon=desktop  
   Terminal=false  
   StartupNotify=false
   ```

   **Or skip the boring edit part from above and enter this:**

   ```
   echo -e "[Desktop Entry]\nType=Application\nExec=xdotool key --delay 100 super+d\nName=Show Desktop\nIcon=desktop\nTerminal=false\nStartupNotify=false" | sudo tee /usr/share/applications/show-desktop.desktop > /dev/null
   ```
3. **Create a Dockitem file in Phank:**

   ```
   nano ~/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/show-desktop.dockitem
   ```

   The contents:

   ```
   [PlankItemsDockItemPreferences]  
   Launcher=file:///usr/share/applications/show-desktop.desktop
   ```

   **Or skip the boring edit part from above and enter this:**

   ```
   /bin/bash -c 'echo -e "[PlankItemsDockItemPreferences]\nLauncher=file:///usr/share/applications/show-desktop.desktop" | tee ~/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/show-desktop.dockitem'
   ```
4. **Make It Permanent**

   Now create a entry for the command above in `gnome-session-properties`. Because if accidentally make a mistake and remove the "Show Desktop" dockitem (uncheck 'Keep In Dock'), so you need to re-create the dockitem file again every time. To solve this problem, we just force to recreate the dockitem file on every session startup:

   ```
   echo -e "[Desktop Entry]\nType=Application\nExec=/bin/bash -c 'echo -e \"[PlankItemsDockItemPreferences]\\\nLauncher=file:///usr/share/applications/show-desktop.desktop\" | tee ~/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/show-desktop.dockitem'\nHidden=false\nX-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true\nName=show-desktop-in-phank" | tee ~/.config/autostart/show-desktop-in-phank.desktop > /dev/null
   ```

Comment: there are some spelling mistakes and errors in your code please review it, also I did all still its not working :-/

Comment: @edwardtorvalds, try this , I remake the whole procedure.  Sorry my bad english, your help in this matter will be very appreciated!

Comment: Hello, it doesn't behave correctly when I click on it. It either takes me to the unity dash or it hides all the windows. And when it hides all the windows, it doesn't let me unhide all the windows again. It is a bit bizarre.